# Is this an appropriate use case for PySpark? Airflow? Apache Beam?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, airflow, apache-beam

I have a complex data processing pipeline that's currently implemented on a single machine in Python.

The pipeline is built around processing objects belonging to a series of custom classes implementing Documents, Pages, Words, etc.  Most of the operations in this pipeline are embarrassingly parallel -- they work on individual documents -- though a few require gathering statistics on the whole set.

The dataset doesn't fit in memory, and the pipeline currently relies on pickling/depickling objects to and from the disk at each stages.  This works but is slow, and it's time to move to a more scalable, distributed architecture.

Ideally **I'd like to be able to write something like this**:

```
distributed_list = read_objects()
for transform in transformations:
    distributed_list = transform(distributed_list)
custom_dataset_object = convert_to_dataset(distributed_list)
custom_dataset_object.save()
```

Where the whole processing stream is broken up into a DAG and parallelized across a cluster.

I've been evaluating **pyspark** for this purpose but am not sure it's the right tool for the task given that I'm not working complex custom objects with lots of methods on them rather than simple datatypes.

**Apache Beam**'s DoFns look like they might accomplish what I'm looking for, but it doesn't seem very widely adopted and I'd like to use the most portable technologies possible.

I could also break this up into a series of **Airflow** jobs, but that seams more manual and brittle than I'd like.

For more experienced big-data engineers, **are these evaluations accurate**?  Would one of these tools (or some other) be best for my job?

Comment: When you said "given that I'm not working complex objects..." do you mean "given that I **am** working on complex objects..."?

Comment: You may want to check out Dask (https://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/), it may be more applicable to your situation and is very easy to setup.

Answer (score 3):

## Apples and Oranges

It really depends on what you want to achieve. For instance, PySpark is not an alternative to Airflow. You can use both, or none of them. You Airflow Operator (the unit of work) can be as simple as "Invoke this PySpark Job".

Airflow is not about the processing steps, but the pipeline itself. You'll want to use it if you want traceability, aggregated log handling, SLAs for your pipelines, conditional processing steps, backfilling control, more complex scheduling and so on.

Airflow shines specially if you want to have *dynamic pipelines*. Edit a few YAML files and there you go, your pipelines now have a few extra steps that compute one extra data piece, backfilled historically and automated to update hourly. Of course that's not for free, you're going to implement that logic that turns configuration into Operators.

## Grape fruit and Grapefruit

Airflow can be your **orchestration** mechanism of choice, but you can decide to achieve the same with a bunch of cron jobs. No sweat.

Choosing the **processing engine** is another sort of problem. Spark is the prom queen these days, and picking Apache Beam is not running away from Spark either. It can operate on Spark and Flink, (batch vs streaming execution engines). But Spark has also a Streaming processing capability getting traction. Choosing between PySpark and Beam is not so much of a scalability concern, but what kind of technology lock-in you'll want to commit yourself to.

I suggest you to pick the processing engine that you experimentally confirm that outperforms the current one. [Sometimes running a command line utility can be faster than distributed jobs](https://aadrake.com/command-line-tools-can-be-235x-faster-than-your-hadoop-cluster.html). Scalability is a problem that you solve as you go, because without experimentation you'll often end up with overengineered systems.